# Why feed a V_OCM outpin pin of a FDA?

Tags: adc, common-mode, differential-amplifier

The Analog Devices reference design [CN0540](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuits-from-the-lab/cn0540.html) (see diagram below) shows an [AD7768-1](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7768-1.pdf) ADC together with a fully-differential ADC driver [ADA4945-1](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4945-1.pdf).

I am wondering why the common-mode voltage pin V_COM of the ADC driver is externally powered by the voltage reference ADR4540+Buffer. According to the ADA4945-1 ADC driver's [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4945-1.pdf), this pin is an output.

Why should you feed an output pin? Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: p. 40 has some explanations

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: What is FDA - what does it mean?

Comment: FDA means Fully Differential Amplifier.

Comment: @Mat If you have time, I'd recommend writing up a summary of the relevant parts of p.40 into an answer.